# Generate Code from activity Diagram using Enterprise Architect

Tags: c++, code-generation, enterprise-architect

I am really struggling trying to second guess how to get EA to generate C++ code from Activity diagrams. I have EA 13 Ultimate and I can generate code from the example EAP project’s activity diagram, specifically the TestSelectionPort example in the "Java Model with Behaviours" package.

I can now generate if statements using an activity diagram of my own. But I want to use a while loop, for loop or do while loop …. then I am lost. 
I can see the example has 2 while loops, and I can generate that code from the example but I cannot for the life of me see HOW to get EA to generate a while loop rather than the if statement. It must be magic!! ha-ha. I can find no property setting or action type that creates a while loop but it must be there somewhere.

I really like the idea of being able to generate an activity diagram form a use case, and it seems to me it would be IDEAL to then embellish to generate boiler plate code from the activity diagram, but man its worse than pulling hen's teeth to work out how. Whilst EA is very good tool, its help is seriously lacking in the help on this area of functionality.

Anybody got any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Terry

Comment: Have you succeed in this? to depict loop in activity diagram you can use a fragment and set the type as loop.

Comment: WOW sorry I missed your comment - sorry!

Comment: Yes I did get it to work 
The build scripts I use are:

Comment: Yes I did get it to work 
The EA  build scripts I use are:
Build "%VSDir%\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "...Project\PhenoSuite.sln" /Build "Debug|x64"

Clean: "%VSDir%\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "%ProjectRoot%\PhenoSuite.sln" /Clean "Debug|x64"

Test: "...packages\NUnit.3.7.1\bin\net-4.5\nunitlite-runner.exe" "...bin\x64\Debug\bin\x64\Debug\Project_NUnitTest.dll

Debug:
Platform:
Debugger: Microsoft.NET
x64: true
Run=true
Default dir: bin/x64/debug
App path: "C:\bin\nunitlite-runner.exe"

Comment: If you got any tips I would appreciate them as it is currently broken.